# How to properly use Instagram Test User Token Generator?

Tags: reactjs, github-pages, instagram-api

I recently made an application that was working with the user token generator and I was properly able to parse through the api. However, after I uploaded my code to GitHub, the token was invalidated (not sure why)

1. I added a Node.js backend that called the token using an env.
2. the token was saved to an env file that was ignored by gitIgnore.

Once the token was invalidated, I tried to generate a new token and it does but after it is generated, it immediately disappears.

Does anyone know the solution to either of my two problems?

TLDR:
Problem 1: Can't push token to gituhub-pages
Problem 2: Can't generate a new token

Edit:
Okay for the second problem I found a weird solution.. the token is generated in a pop up window. If I close that window or refresh the page, the token is invalidated. Instead I just closed the entire chrome window and it works now..

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you how to create long-lived token for instagram:

Facebook token generator seems to be broken, but you can generate your own long-lived access token following OAuth2 workflow (replace `{}` placeholders with your own values):

1. In your browser, go to:

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={your-client-id}&client_secret={your-client-secret}&redirect_uri={a-valid-redirect-url}&scope=user_profile,user_media&response_type=code
```

2. Login to your Instagram account and accept your application to access your data
3. You should be redirected to `{a-valid-redirect-url}?code=xxxxx#_` then copy to {code} query string value without the `#_` at the end
4. Use Postman to execute a `POST` request to  `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token` with `x-www-form-urlencoded` params

   - `client_id`: {your-client-id}
   - `client_secret`: {your-client-secret}
   - `grant_type`: authorization_code
   - `redirect_uri`: {a-valid-redirect-url}
   - `code`: {the code you extracted from query string}
5. You should get a short-lived access-token response such as:

```json
{
    "access_token": "IGQVxxxxxxxxxx…",
    "user_id": xxxxxxxxxx
}
```

6. Exchange your short-lived access-token with a long-lived one: use Postman to execute a `GET` request to `https://graph.instagram.com/access_token` with query params:

   - `client_id`: {your-client-id}
   - `client_secret`: {your-client-secret}
   - `grant_type`: ig_exchange_token
   - `access_token`: {the short-lived access_token}
7. You should get a long-lived access-token response such as:

```json
{
    "access_token": "IGQxxxxx…",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 5169852
}
```

Comment: sephvand hey thanks for the response but I think that is the same thing as using the user token generator on the facebook developers website. I gave it a try and ended up with a similarly length token that starts with the same couple of letters. Added it to my axios get request and get the same error with the token not being correct. I know for a fact the code is correct because it was working earlier. Any other suggestions?